# Появляются лишние пустые списки

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, csv, список

```
import xlrd
import csv
from os import sys

def csv_from_excel(excel_file):
    workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(excel_file)
    all_worksheets = workbook.sheet_names()
    for worksheet_name in all_worksheets:
        worksheet = workbook.sheet_by_name(worksheet_name)
        with open('{}.csv'.format(worksheet_name), 'w', encoding = 'utf-8') as your_csv_file:
            wr = csv.writer(your_csv_file, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
            for rownum in range(worksheet.nrows):
                wr.writerow(worksheet.row_values(rownum))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    csv_from_excel(sys.argv[1])
```

Используя данный модуль я конвертирую Excel файл в CSV затем

```
import csv

with open('Лист1.csv', 'r') as f:
  reader = csv.reader(f)
  your_list = list(reader)

print(your_list)
```

сделав из него список я получаю на выходе, соответственно пустые списки не нужны.

> [['COMPUTERNAME1.DOMAIN1.COM', 'DOMAIN1\USERNAME1'], [],
>   ['COMPUTERNAME3.DOMAIN3.COM', 'DOMAIN3\USERNAME3'], [],
>   ['COMPUTERNAME4.DOMAIN1.COM', 'DOMAIN1\USERNAME4'], [],
>   ['COMPUTERNAME5.DOMAIN2.COM', 'DOMAIN2\USERNAME5'], [],
>   ['COMPUTERNAME6.DOMAIN3.COM', 'DOMAIN3\USERNAME6'], [],
>   ['COMPUTERNAME7.DOMAIN1.COM', 'DOMAIN1\USERNAME7'], [],
>   ['COMPUTERNAME9.DOMAIN3.COM', 'DOMAIN3\USERNAME9'], [],
>   ['COMPUTERNAME0.DOMAIN1.COM', 'DOMAIN1\USERNAME0'], []]

Где может быть ошибка?

Исходный файл Excel

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Исходный файл CSV

> COMPUTERNAME1.DOMAIN1.COM,"DOMAIN1\USERNAME1"
>
> COMPUTERNAME3.DOMAIN3.COM,"DOMAIN3\USERNAME3"
>
> COMPUTERNAME4.DOMAIN1.COM,"DOMAIN1\USERNAME4"
>
> COMPUTERNAME5.DOMAIN2.COM,"DOMAIN2\USERNAME5"
>
> COMPUTERNAME6.DOMAIN3.COM,"DOMAIN3\USERNAME6"
>
> COMPUTERNAME7.DOMAIN1.COM,"DOMAIN1\USERNAME7"
>
> COMPUTERNAME9.DOMAIN3.COM,"DOMAIN3\USERNAME9"
>
> COMPUTERNAME0.DOMAIN1.COM,"DOMAIN1\USERNAME0"

Comment: Приложите к вопросу тот csv, а то ваш случай с экселем повторять не охото :)

Comment: @gil9red я немножко не понял как приложить, поэтому скопировал содержимое, но судя по Excel там пропуск строчки идет

Comment: Хм, ну значит в этом и проблема -- лишних пустых строках. Значит, лучше разобраться как сохранять без них либо при считывании убрать пустые `[]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте сохранять `csv` так:

```
with open('{}.csv'.format(worksheet_name), 'w', encoding='utf-8', newline='')
#                                                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Либо можно бороться с ошибкой, удалив пустые подсписки:

```
your_list = list(filter(None, your_list))
```

Comment: Первый вариант не прошел, выдал ошибку.
А вот второй убрал пустые списки.

Comment: А какая ошибка была?

Comment: `TypeError: 'newline' is an invalid keyword argument for this function`

Comment: Я вас обманул, этот параметр нужно у `open` указывать :)